# removeAt not functioning in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've a list of objects, I want to remove the element with its index, here's my code but it doesn't work, returns an error saying:`unresolved reference: removeAt println(sachmelebi.removeAt(asd))`

```kotlin
fun main() {
    data class SachmelebiClass( 
        val name: String,
        val link: String
    )

    val sachmelebi = listOf(
        SachmelebiClass(
            "ხინკალი",
            "https://www.google.com/search?q=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&oq=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l6.1143j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
        ),
        SachmelebiClass(
            "aa",
            "aaa"
        ),
        SachmelebiClass(
            "bb",
            "bbb"
        )
    )
    
    val randomColor = sachmelebi.random()
    println()
    val asd = sachmelebi.indexOf(randomColor)

    sachmelebi.removeAt(asd)
```

Answer (score 2):

`listOf()` returns a read-only view of the underlying `List` so you need a mutable List as follows:

```kotlin
val sachmelebi = mutableListOf(
    SachmelebiClass(
        "ხინკალი",
        "https://www.google.com/search?q=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&oq=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l6.1143j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
    ),
    SachmelebiClass(
        "aa",
        "aaa"
    ),
    SachmelebiClass(
        "bb",
        "bbb"
    )
)
```

<s>You can also do the following so that you can access `removeAt()` method (as @Tenfour04 mentioned, there is an overloaded version of [listOf()][1] that actually returns an immutable List and thus you should be careful while performing this cast) `(sachmelebi as MutableList).removeAt(asd)`</s>

(*As discussed in the comments with @Tenfour04, the striked-through suggestion has so many disadvantages that it is better to not even mention it. Thanks @Tenfour04 for the hints.*)

---

Another possibility, most probably a better one, is to stick with read-only Lists and do the following instead:

```kotlin
val finalSachmelebi = sachmelebi.minus(randomColor)
```

This will create a new List with the final result. Mutable lists is usually a source of bugs, and that is why using read-only lists is usually preferable.

Comment: Be careful with `as MutableList`. Some overload(s) of `listOf` produce truly immutable Lists  that throw exceptions when attempting to mutate them.

Comment: Very good point @Tenfour04. Thanks for pointing that. I will add this info to the answer.

Comment: Oh, and another possible risk with doing it is if you got your List from some other class. That class may have exposed a MutableList as a read-only List because it doesn't want outside classes to mutate it, so mutating it externally could break functionality in that class.

Comment: Also true. I will adjust my answer to remove this suggestion. It feels it has more disadvantages than advantages. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

```
val newList = sachmelebi.toMutableList().removeAt(asd)
```